# Removing scientific notation figure on Y axis plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I am very new to MatLab. I am sorry if my question is basic. I am plotting three lines.

[image]

The problem is that if you look at Y-tick, you see percentage figures, but there is a very small number in scientific notation:

-2.7556e-15%

How do I get rid of this number? Or how do I replace 0% instead of this figure?

This is my code

```
clf;
plot(mkt_wgt,'b- x','DisplayName','mkt_wgt','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',10,'MarkerEdgeColor','b');
hold on;
plot(W_BL_Idzorek,'r- x','DisplayName','W_BL_Idzorek','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',10,'MarkerEdgeColor','r');
plot(W_100_TF1,'g- x','DisplayName','W_100_TF1','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',10,'MarkerEdgeColor','g');
hold off;
grid on;
title('Effect of Casuality');
set(gca, 'xTickLabels', {'IRN1' 'IRN2' 'IRN3' 'IRN4' 'IRN5' 'IRN6' 'IRN7' 'IRN'});
set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation');%turn it 90 degree
ylabel('Air Pollution Casuality');
set(gca, 'yTickLabels', num2str(100.*get(gca,'yTick')','%g%%'));
legend({'Tehran','Tel.Aviv','Kabul'}, 'location', 'southoutside', 'orientation', 'horizontal');
```

Best regards,
Mariam

Comment: If your labels are only going to be integer percentages you can use [`fix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) in your `num2str` call to round towards zero, or cast the values as [integers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the revise in y-tick to remove the scientific figure.

```
set(gca, 'yTickLabels', num2str(fix(100.*get(gca,'yTick'))','%g%%'));
```

We just add fix function in nu2str.